# Last state of edit text still showing as some kind of shadow?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Well, this is weird, so, I have a control. A simple `CardView` with `RelativeLayout` and some other controls. One of them, is an `EditText`. Basically, there are some different actions that I do based on `EditText`'s focus change.

1. Showing / hiding "X" button, which is to clear the edittext. (When doing the #1, I swap `toLeftOf` property of `EditText` between X ad Search icon - thus shrink/growing the `EditText` automatically)
2. Adding / Removing Hint text, in this case, "Tap to Search" text.

Strangely, after I've done it, there's still a trail of past state, still printed.

Here's the unfocused `EditText`
[image]

And here's the focused one
[image]

Note that there're shadows of "Tap to search" and "pre-shrinked" `EditText` line below the X.

Here's my Java Snippet related to the `EditText`

```
    queryStringEText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                clearIButton.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) queryStringEText.getLayoutParams()).
                        addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, clearIButton.getId());

                //Hide hint text
                queryStringEText.setHint("");

                //Show the keyboard
                ((InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).
                        showSoftInput(queryStringEText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
            } else {
                clearIButton.setVisibility(GONE);
                ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) queryStringEText.getLayoutParams()).
                        addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, searchIButton.getId());

                //Hide hint text
                queryStringEText.setHint("Tap to search");

                //Hide the keyboard
                ((InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).
                        hideSoftInputFromWindow(queryStringEText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

And here's the xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#80000000"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addon_search_panel_search"
        style="@style/FoodMap_ImageButtonWithNoBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="@dimen/default_content_padding"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addon_search_panel_clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/addon_search_panel_search"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_content_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/default_content_padding"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_yellow_24dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/addon_search_panel_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/addon_search_panel_search"
        android:hint="Tap to search"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textColorHint="#aaa"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/FoodMap_colorAccent"
        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**How to remove those "shadow of the past"?**

P.S. Tried `querySearchEText.requestLayout()` after each focus change but nothing happened.

P.S.S. The "Tap to search" shadow persists even after I typed in some text.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried requesting layout for parent instead `.getParent().requestLayout();` ?

Though the easiest solution would be to put both ImageButtons into `LinearLayout` and position your `EditText` to the left left of that layout.

**EDIT:**

```
 queryStringEText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                clearIButton.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

                //Hide hint text
                queryStringEText.setHint("");

                //Show the keyboard
                ((InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).
                        showSoftInput(queryStringEText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
            } else {
                clearIButton.setVisibility(GONE);

                //Hide hint text
                queryStringEText.setHint("Tap to search");

                //Hide the keyboard
                ((InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).
                        hideSoftInputFromWindow(queryStringEText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

And xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#80000000"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/controls_layout">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/addon_search_panel_clear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/default_content_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/default_content_padding"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_close_yellow_24dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/addon_search_panel_search"
                style="@style/FoodMap_ImageButtonWithNoBackground"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:padding="@dimen/default_content_padding"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/addon_search_panel_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/controls_layout"
            android:hint="Tap to search"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="#aaa"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/FoodMap_colorAccent"
            tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: tried both, none worked. shadow from edit text still persists.

Comment: But did you remove `addRule` calls when trying `LinearLayout` approach?

Comment: Yeah ofc. `LinearLayout` doesn't have such rule, so I commented it out.

Comment: I think there's some misunderstanding, will add code

Comment: Commented it out = removed it btw.. exactly like what u posted

Answer (score 0):

This is silly, I accidentally add 2 identical views on top of each other. So when the top is going translucent, the bottom will block it from being really translucent.

So, I fix it simply by not adding 2 identical views.